# Schema.org mainContentOfPage property is not recognized by Google

Tags: google-search, html5, microdata

I'm developing a website for a property portal, that when a user enter the required inputs it shows a listing of the properties. I want to give them a product that includes Microdata. But when I define my body as a `WebPage` and set the main tag of the page to have `mainContentOfPage` it says Google does not know this value.

Any ideas why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta content="True" name="HandheldFriendly">
    <meta content="320" name="MobileOptimized">
    <link href="apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
    <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <!--[if IE]>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <![endif]-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/modernizr-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/picturefill.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <header aria-labelledby="banner-desc" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" role="banner">
  <nav aria-labelledby="topnav-desc" class="top-nav" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" role="navigation">
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">
      <span id="topnav-desc">Top</span>
      navigation
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <li itemprop="url">
        <a href="#" itemprop="name">
          <svg class="closed-icon">
            <use xlink:href="#lock-closed"></use>
          </svg>
          Login
        </a>
      </li>
      <li itemprop="url">
        <a href="#" itemprop="name">
          <svg class="heart-icon">
            <use xlink:href="#heart"></use>
          </svg>
          Mine favoritter
        </a>
      </li>
      <li itemprop="url">
        <a href="#" itemprop="name">
          <svg class="account-icon">
            <use xlink:href="#account-icon"></use>
          </svg>
          Min konto
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h1 itemprop="headline">
    <a class="logo" href="#">
      Justhome
      <svg class="logo">
        <use xlink:href="#logo"></use>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </h1>
  <h2 id="banner-desc" itemprop="description">Nordjysk boligside</h2>
  <nav class="main-nav" id="content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Info</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
    <!-- main content -->
    <main aria-labelledby="main-desc" itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" role="main" tabindex="-1">
      <h1 id="main-desc">Søg lejligheder, garager og kontorer</h1>
      <!-- search field -->
      <div class="search-field-wrapper">
        <form role="search">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              Vælg din kategori:
            </legend>
            <!-- search checkbox -->
            <label>
              <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
              Lejligheder
            </label>
            <label>
              <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
              Garager
            </label>
            <label>
              <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
              kontorer
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <!-- search input -->
          <label class="visually-hidden" for="s">
            Indtast dit
            <span id="search-desc">postnr</span>
          </label>
          <input aria-required="true" id="s" name="search" placeholder="Indtast dit postnr." required title="venligst udfyld dette felt" type="search">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Søg">
          <label>
            <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
            Avanceret søgning
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
      <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" role="article">
        <header>
          <h2 itemprop="headline">Article Title 1</h2>
        </header>
        <section itemprop="articleBody">
          <h3>Article body</h3>
        </section>
        <footer>
          Footnote 1
        </footer>
      </article>
    </main>
    <aside aria-labelledby="comp-desc" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" role="complementary">
      <p id="comp-desc">Reklamer</p>
    </aside>
    <footer aria-labelledby='footer-desc' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/WPFooter' role='contentinfo'>
  <p id='footer-desc'>footer content</p>
  <address>
    <a href='mailto:info@crafthouse.agency'>Kontakt udvikler</a>
  </address>
  <p>
    <small>
      © 2015
      <a href='http://crafthouse.agency'>Crafthouse Agency</a>
    </small>
  </p>
</footer>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’ve removed the additional questions about your markup. Please create a separate post for each question. -- Also note that Schema.org terms are case-sensitive (I’ve corrected the case). And about the terminology: You are using the syntax Microdata (not Microformats).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) expects a [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) as value, but you are using `Blog` (which is not a child of `WebPageElement`).

You seem to use it like a property to denote the "main entity" of a page, but this is not appropriate. A property for that is [currently under discussion](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/301).

Side note: It is not appropriate to use the `url` property for each navigation link. The `url` property of a [`SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement) would have to give the URL of the whole navigation, not the URLs of the navigation links it contains.